# Spring tiles jsp table records from other class

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, postgresql, tiles

I try to configure spring with tiles and create a website - one to mane relation -> Klient - Pobyt and got a question regarding configuration.

I have got a class Klient and a class Pobyt, I also set up a view, but I am getting a null pointer exception when using `= ${klient.idKlienta}` in order to connect a klient to a list of pobyt`s. 
I am getting a org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:- Error in postgresSQL syntax. 
Using a concrete value in sql works fine. 
Any idea what is wrong?

Could yoy help?

Here is the .jsp:

```
<%@page language="Java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html >
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<sql:setDataSource var="postgres" driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MAS_PRO" user="postgres"
password="qwe" scope="session" />   

<sql:query dataSource="${postgres}" var="result">
SELECT * from Pobyt
where idklienta=${klient.idKlienta} // when entering an existing id fe. 1 it works fine
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Id Pobytu</th>
<th>Data od</th>
<th>do</th>
<th>Id klienta</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.idpobytu}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.datazameldowania}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.datawymeldowania}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.idklienta}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

PobytBean and KlientBean:

```
public class PobytBean {

private Integer idPobytu;
private Date dataZameldowania;
private Date dataWymeldowania;
private Integer idKlienta;

public class KlientBean {

private Integer idKlienta;
private String imie;
private String nazwisko; 
private String nrTelefonu;
private String eMail;
```

Klient and Pobyt

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Klient")
public class Klient implements Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="idKlienta")
private Integer idKlienta;
@Column(name = "imie")
private String imie;
@Column(name = "nazwisko")
private String nazwisko; 
@Column(name = "nrTelefonu")
private String nrTelefonu;
@Column(name = "eMail")
private String eMail;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Pobyt")
 public class Pobyt implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "idPobytu")
private Integer idPobytu;
@Column(name = "dataZameldowania")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataZameldowania;
@Column(name = "dataWymeldowania")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataWymeldowania;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idKlienta", insertable=false, updatable=false)
public Klient klient;

private Integer idKlienta;
```

Here is the .jsp from where I try to get to the concrete list of pobyts

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Pobyty</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Lista klientow</h1>
<c:if test="${!empty klienci}">
    <table align="left" border="1">     
        <tr>
            <th>Klient id</th>
            <th>Imie</th>
            <th>Nazwisko</th>
            <th>Nr Telefonu</th>
            <th>e-Mail</th>
            <th>Akcja</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${klienci}" var="klient">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${klient.idKlienta}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${klient.imie}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${klient.nazwisko}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${klient.nrTelefonu}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${klient.eMail}" /></td>
                <td><a href="openKlient.html?id=${klient.idKlienta}">Otwórz</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
  </body>
  </html>
```

*Update*:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: org.postgresql.util.psqlexception error syntax error at end of input
(Position 44)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2101)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1834)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:510)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doEndTag(QueryTagSupport.java:224)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.openKlient_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(openKlient_jsp.java:202)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.openKlient_jsp._jspService(openKlient_jsp.java:91)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.mainTemplate_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f3(mainTemplate_jsp.java:180)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.mainTemplate_jsp._jspService(mainTemplate_jsp.java:94)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And the "server is complaining" about:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/mainTemplate.jsp'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

root cause

```
org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/mainTemplate.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:692)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I tried to search for logs and what I have found is:

Tomcat log:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Feb/2014:18:34:40 +0100] "GET /MAS_Koncowy/welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1786
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Feb/2014:18:34:43 +0100] "GET /MAS_Koncowy/klienci.html HTTP/1.1" 200 2441
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [22/Feb/2014:18:34:44 +0100] "GET /MAS_Koncowy/openKlient.html?id=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 17745
```

In Pg_log I have found what I`ve already posted:

```
2014-02-22 18:43:36 CET error syntax error at end of input (Position 44)
2014-02-22 18:43:36 CET Query:  
SELECT * from Pobyt
where idKlienta =
```

So the problem is the idKlienta is not passed to the query? How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for trying to include some useful detail. You forgot a couple of crucial bits though - the *full, exact text of the PostgreSQL error message*, and the *exact text of the query that produced it*. You can get the query from your application server logs with hibernate query logging enabled, or by setting `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and getting it from the PostgreSQL logs. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info

Comment: Hi, 
thx for your reply. Do you mean this infos?:

Comment: That's half the information; you've shown the error message. Now get the *SQL text of the query that produced the error*. I advised you how in my previous comment. Edit your question with the info and comment here when done.

Comment: Hi,
I updated the question. Hope those are the informations you needed?

Comment: Well, I guess `klient.idKlienta` is null then...

Comment: Any idea, where the mistake is? In one of the .jsp`s I've created a: <a href="openKlient.html?id=${klient.idKlienta}">Otwórz</a> and the value is passed to the url (fe. http://localhost:8080/MAS_Koncowy/openKlient.html?id=1), but not passed to the database... I've checked the code like 1000 times and can not find what the problem is...

Comment: I don't see anything obvious I'm afraid. In your position I would be attaching a debugger to the app server, setting a breakpoint where it loads my JSP, and watching what happens step by step, setting appropriate breakpoints and rerunning, etc. It's a bit of a slow process but I don't see any obvious answers here.